# Oracle Aggregate(SUM function) after self-join

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table which contains ID, PARENT_ID AND COUNT.

EX)

```
+-----+-----------------------+--------------------------+
| ID  |       PARENT_ID       |         COUNT            |...
+-----+-----------------------+--------------------------+
|  1  |        NULL           |          40              |...
|  2  |         1             |          10              |...
|  3  |         1             |          20              |...
|  4  |        NULL           |          35              |...
+-----+-----------------------+--------------------------+
```

And, i want result the sum of parent and sibling's count.

> ID 1's count = ID 1's count + ID 2's count + ID 3's count

RESULT)

```
+-----+-----------------------+--------------------------+
| ID  |       PARENT_ID       |         COUNT            |...
+-----+-----------------------+--------------------------+
|  1  |        NULL           |          70              |...
|  2  |         1             |          10              |...
|  3  |         1             |          20              |...
|  4  |        NULL           |          35              |...
+-----+-----------------------+--------------------------+
```

I used connect by to get the desired result, but I want to change the method as the above method uses too much oracle cpu.

Is there any way I can do this using sum function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the self join as follows:

```
SQL> with dataa (ID, PARENT_ID, CNT) as
  2  (SELECT 1  , NULL, 40 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  3  SELECT 2  ,  1  , 10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  4  SELECT 3  ,  1  , 20 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  5  SELECT 4  , NULL, 35 FROM DUAL)
  6  -- your query starts from here
  7  SELECT D1.ID, D1.PARENT_ID, D1.CNT + COALESCE(SUM(D2.CNT),0)
  8  FROM DATAA D1 LEFT JOIN DATAA D2
  9  ON D1.ID = D2.PARENT_ID
 10  GROUP BY D1.ID, D1.PARENT_ID, D1.CNT
 11  ORDER BY D1.ID;

        ID  PARENT_ID D1.CNT+COALESCE(SUM(D2.CNT),0)
---------- ---------- ------------------------------
         1                                        70
         2          1                             10
         3          1                             20
         4                                        35

SQL>
```

Comment: @Yong . . . This works for your particular data sample, but it is not going to work if your hierarchy is deeper than one level.  Unfortunately, the question is quite ambiguous, because "sibling" is not the correct description, "child" is.  It is not clear if you want just the immediate children or all descendants.